# How does one show that the series converges almost surely?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ be random variables. Define $C:=\{ \omega \ | \ \sum X_n(\omega) \text{ converges} \}$. There is such $q\in(0,1)$ that for all $n\in \mathbb N: P\{ |X_n| \geq q^n\}\leq q^n$. Show that $P(C)=1$.

My attempt:

Define $E_n:=\{ |X_n| \geq q^n\}$. Apply Borel-Cantelli: $P(\limsup E_n)=0$. Next I was hoping to show that $\Omega\setminus C \subset \limsup E_n$ (if that works, we're done).

Let $\omega\in \Omega\setminus C$, therefore $$\exists \varepsilon>0 \ \ \forall m \in \mathbb N \ \ \exists n \geq m \ \ (| X_1(\omega)+\ldots+X_n(\omega) |\geq \varepsilon)$$ and we want to show that $\omega \in\limsup E_n$ $$\forall m\in \mathbb N \ \ \exists n\geq m \ \ (|X_n(\omega)|\geq q^n)$$

Let $m \in \mathbb N$, choose $\varepsilon=q^m$, then for all $n \geq m$:

$$| X_1(\omega)|+\ldots+|X_n(\omega)|\geq| X_1(\omega)+\ldots+X_n(\omega) |\geq q^m \geq q^n$$

It seems like we're close but I can't finish the argument. Any hints are hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably simpler to prove that the complement of $\limsup_{n\to+\infty}E_n$ is contained in $C$.

Indeed, if $\omega$ is not in $\limsup_{n\to+\infty}E_n$, then there is $N=N(\omega)$ such that for $n\geqslant N$, $\omega\notin E_n$. We thus have $|X_n(\omega)|\leqslant q^n$ for these $n$, which proves the convergence of the series $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}|X_n(\omega)|$.